# Sentry PHP - Determining if the exception/event was actually sent successfully

Tags: php, sentry

I've implemented the PHP library against a Sentry onpremise installation into a project which is working great, I have no problems with the functionality when its set up to work.

What I'd like to do is determine when for any reason the actual sentry recording fails, however struggling to find where in the application flow Sentry returns something that can be utilised to determine 'recording success'.

I've forced a failure by changing the DSN address being used in the `Raven_Client` construct to an invalid URL and can confirm events are NOT being recorded - which is expected.

The Sentry `Raven_Client` exposes a method `getLastEventID()` which seems to contain an ID at the creation of the event itself, and not upon successful submission to the server (which I expected it to be, and had done a check on to display my error page).

There is also a `getLastError()` method, which is null at the point my application (CodeIgniter) has entered the `My_Exceptions::show_exception()` method to display an error page to the client.

The SentryID is populated, and the error is null, and I'm not sure what else there is available to check on to know that the error report actually failed to be recorded.

The reason I want to do this is so that I can show a different view to the user (that doesn't say 'Support have been notified'; as they haven't) and also the functionality to check that `$sentryEventId` and show a custom feedback form obviously needs to be hidden as the sentryEventId is invalid and the feedback wont go anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on version 1.10.0 of the Sentry PHP SDK and are not using any async way of sending the events (the default) the `getLastEventID()` will be `null` if the `send` action fails.

See also [the PR](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-php/pull/667) that introduced this change.